# Simple Java drawing program with shapes

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a drawing program with swing for a school assignment. You're supposed to be able to draw three shapes (dots, ovals and rectangles) in three different color. I'm struggling with making the mouselisteners use the DrawView class to actually draw anything. I've tried a bunch of different solutions but I feel like I might be lacking something in some of the classes.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    
    public class DrawControl extends JFrame {
    
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private Color currColor;
        private Shape currShape;
    
        public DrawControl() {
            JFrame drawingProgram = new JFrame("Drawing Program");
            drawingProgram.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            drawingProgram.setSize(800, 800);
            drawingProgram.setLocation(600, 50);
    
            JPanel drawArea = new JPanel();
            drawArea.setBackground(Color.white);
            drawArea.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    
            JPanel menu = new JPanel();
            menu.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    
            JButton buttonBlack = new JButton("Black");
            JButton buttonRed = new JButton("Red");
            JButton buttonGreen = new JButton("Green");
            JButton buttonDot = new JButton("Dot");
            JButton buttonOval = new JButton("Oval");
            JButton buttonRect = new JButton("Rect");
            JButton buttonUndo = new JButton("Undo");
            JButton buttonSave = new JButton("Save");
            JButton buttonLoad = new JButton("Load");
    
            menu.add(buttonBlack);
            menu.add(buttonRed);
            menu.add(buttonGreen);
            menu.add(buttonDot);
            menu.add(buttonOval);
            menu.add(buttonRect);
            menu.add(buttonUndo);
            menu.add(buttonSave);
            menu.add(buttonLoad);
    
    
            buttonBlack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            });
    
            buttonRed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setColor(Color.RED);
                }
            });
    
            buttonGreen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
            });
    
            buttonDot.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setShape(Shape.DOT);
                }
            });
    
            buttonOval.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setShape(Shape.OVAL);
                }
            });
    
            buttonRect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setShape(Shape.RECT);
                }
            });
    
            MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    DrawView f = new DrawView();
                    repaint();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    
                }
            };
    
            JLabel current = new JLabel("...");
    
            drawingProgram.add(drawArea);
            drawArea.add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            drawArea.add(current, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            drawingProgram.setVisible(true);
        }
    
        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.currColor = color;
        }
    
        public void setShape(Shape shape) {
            this.currShape = shape;
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            DrawControl drawControl = new DrawControl();
        }
    }
    
    **************************************************************************************************
    
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    
    public class DrawView extends JPanel {
    
        private DrawModel drawModel;
    
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            drawShape(g, this.drawModel);
        }
    
        private void drawShape(Graphics g, DrawModel s) {
            if (s == null) {
                return;
            }
            g.setColor(s.getColor());
            if (s.getShapeType() != Shape.RECT) {
                g.fillOval(s.getX(), s.getY(), s.getWidth(), s.getHeight());
            } else {
                g.fillRect(s.getX(), s.getY(), s.getWidth(), s.getHeight());
            }
        }
    }
    **************************************************************************************************

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class DrawModel {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Shape shapeType;
    private Color color;

    public DrawModel(int x, int y, int width, int height, Shape shapeType, Color color){
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public Shape getShapeType() {
        return shapeType;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

}
    **************************************************************************************************

public enum Shape {
    DOT,
    RECT,
    OVAL
}
```

Comment: You are doing many things incorrectly.  For example, you are extending JFrame which you shouldn't do.  But then you are also creating an instance of JFrame.  Please check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) section on how to paint.

Comment: first thing I've noticed is that you are not doing anything with your mouselistener, you have to add the mouselistener to an object ... e.g.  drawArea - drawArea.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

Comment: Nor do I see where you are creating any instances of DrawModel. So drawShape will return immediately since `s` is apparently null.

Comment: My suggestion is to start fresh.  Use a JFrame to create your GUI.  Test it.  Create your drawing JPanel.  Test it.  Create your button and display JPanels.  Test them.  Create your application model.  Test it.  The idea is to write a tiny bit of code, maybe 10 lines, and test it.  If you encounter problems, they're probably in the 10 lines you just added.  Run literally hundreds of tests.